# Composition of functions is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> If $f\circ g$ ($f$ composed with $g$) is constant, then which of the following is constant?
>
> 1. $f$
> 2. $g$
> 3. $g \circ f$ ($g$ composed with $f$)
> 4. Both $f$ and $g$
> 5. Both $g$ and $g \circ f$

I think if $f \circ g$ is constant then at least one of $f$ and $g$ should be constant, is it correct? So my idea is that $g \circ f$ must be constant. But some people answered this question with last option, $g$ and $g \circ f$.

Please somebody help me with this question with some details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set $g(x)$ to be $\begin{cases}1&x\in\mathbb Q\\-1&x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$. Set $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: How about substituting in some simple functions and constant functions for $g$ and $f$ to try and get a better idea?

Comment: Yes in your example fog is constant.Very interesting.

Comment: But gof is not constant.So in this example none of the f,g,gof is constant.So what will be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f:Y\rightarrow X$.

Take $X=\left\{ a,b,c\right\} $
and $Y=\left\{ u,v,w\right\} $ both having exactly $3$ elements.

Prescribe $g$ by $a\mapsto u$, $b\mapsto u$ and $c\mapsto v$ and $f$ by
$u\mapsto a$, $v\mapsto a$ and $w\mapsto c$.

Then  $f\circ g$ is constant but $f$ and $g$ and $g\circ f$ are not.

In fact if the domain of $g$ would not coincide with the codomain
of $f$  (and this is not guaranteed by the existence of a constant $f\circ g$) then $g\circ f$ would not even be defined.